# MySQL under what scenario suitable to use WHERE EXISTS

Tags: mysql, performance, where, exists, query-performance

I recently just noticed that `WHERE EXISTS` can slow down the operation badly. E.g.

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE count(*) as aggregate
from `table_1`
where exists (select *
              from `table_2`
              where `table_1`.`fk_id` = `table_2`.`id`
                and `name` = 'john');
```

**79 seconds**

**VS**

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE count(*) as aggregate
from `table_1`
inner join `table_2` on `table_1`.`fk_id` = `table_2`.`id`
where `table_2`.`name` = 'John';
```

**72 milliseconds**

- `table_1` has total *4,723,710 records*
- `table_2` has total *1,236 records*

Just wanted to know, since the performance of `WHERE EXISTS` so bad, under what scenario do we need to use this?

Comment: I don't think exists should take time like 79 second and join take 72 milliseconds..... Test once again may be you had lag

Comment: Now I tried, it took 85.7 seconds. I've updated the total number of records for each table in the question.

Comment: Can you explain what you aim behind this ? If u need total number or just match once something in more detail

Comment: And try to match table 2 to with table 1 as it has less entry may be there is some change in time but i am not really sure about this

Comment: Want to get the total records of `table_1`, where the `table_2` name must be **John**

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table, plus the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: It is very slow in 8.0.29 - i have  a query with all the right indexes - it takes forever - it looks like mysql builds the result from the subquery then it executes conditions. Any other rdbms I worked with processes these super-fast.

Answer (score 1):

Not a fair test.  Your example is about as close as you can get between using `JOIN` to using `EXISTS`.

Also, it probably gave a different result -- What if there are 2 Johns?  The `JOIN` would count both; the `EXISTS` would count only once.

`EXISTS` is a "semi-join".  It is better than `JOIN` in cases where it can stop short of scanning for all rows that match.  Instead, it stops with the first match.  If there is a useful index, semi-join does not necessarily help much.  If not, it could be a big speed up.

In the past, `IN ( SELECT ... )` was notoriously inefficient.  `EXISTS (SELECT * )` is often a better choice.

Search around stackoverflow.com for more instances of `EXISTS`.  I think you will find a variety.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind to provide an example query for both `EXISTS` & `JOIN`? _(P/S: The example that I show is in our production DB)_